# Implementation Outlined text field Input with lable text in dropdown menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

[Image displays a drop down menu, with gender details, such as male, female and others. Thankyou in Advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKca6.png)

Answer (score 0):

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

**CODE :**

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_sharp),
            onChanged: (v) {},
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 1.5)),
              labelText: "Gender",
            ),
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(
                  "Male",
                ),
                value: "MALE",
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(
                  "Female",
                ),
                value: "FEMALE",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```